# Chrome makes page content blank after minimizing and reopening browser

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-canvas, pdf.js

I updated Chrome to latest **official stable release** and observed a weird behavior.

When browser is minimized and restored in any webpage, due to some sort of optimization done by Chrome, the entire page will be rendered again where it fails to render some elements like PDF, Canvas etc. But the same cases works well in Firefox, Opera, IE11, Edge and other browsers. Is this an issue with latest Chrome build? Is there any fix for this?

- **OS:** Windows 10 64bit
- **Chrome Version:** v62.0.3202.89, 64bit
- **Settings:**: Hardware Acceleration - Enabled (Default Setting of Chrome)

**Test Case:** [PDFJS-Viewer](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html)

**Steps to Reproduce:**

- Open PDFJS viewer in chrome.
- Minimize the browser
- Restore/Reopen the browser

The same case works fine when hardware acceleration is disabled.

**Screenshot: When You open Page for the first time.**
[image: When You open Page for the first time]

**Screenshot: After minimizing and restoring/reopening the page.**
[image]

Comment: For what it's worth, I can't reproduce on the osX build. Could be related with  [this bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=778873)  which should be fixed in current 64 Canary version. As a workaround, you could try to force a style change on window's focus (`window.onfocus = e => {if(e.target !== window) return; let docEl=document.documentElement, s=docEl.style; s.display='inline-block'; docEl.offsetWidth; s.display='block'};`). If you still experience this bug in latest canary version, feel free to file a bug report to chromium's team.

Comment: Kaiido, the issue is there only in Windows and with latest Stable version only (v62.0.3202.89). In Mac, it works pretty well with same version of chrome.

Comment: Yes that's what I said with *I can't reproduce on the osX build*. Did you tried the latest canary build (v.64) on windows? If it works there, it means they already fixed it.

Comment: I just tried with latest beta(v63) and canary. It works pretty well in both. Thanks for the info :)